# How to access virtual address via terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, io, virtual-memory, arm64

i'm trying to read & write to register by using the busybox devmem command.
I printed its base address from the driver's source code and received the following address:
0xffffff800bdd0000

I assume that this is a virtual kernel address.
How can i convert it to the physical address, so i can use busybox devmem?
I'm trying to perform it from the terminal without any need in programming.

Comment: Hmmm… sounds incredible to me (in 2022) that you actually read whatever physical or virtual absolute address in the driver source code. (because drivers are generally written base address agnostic). What sort of device is it ? On which sort of bus does it stand ? (we need to know if corresponding ios registers are memory remapped or not)

Comment: I'm using nvidia jetson xavier nx (ubuntu 18). The device is the video block of nvidia's gpu. I thought that maybe there's some tool that i can use for the translation.

Comment: Do you explicitely mean the Jetson xavier nx plugged into some **PCIe bus** of some **x86_64** arch or not exactly ?

Comment: Asking for close because of many important missing details in the question. Since the Jetson xavier nx exists with many possible different interfaces with the system and that the method to access to the card's real addresses depends on those interfaces, we just cannot answer.

Comment: I understand. My setup is working directly on the developer kit of the jetson. It has arm64 cpu. And the gpu is connected on the internal memory bus

Comment: Please copy that utmost important piece of information as part of your question. I cancel my close request.

Comment: And also please copy to your question the output of cat /proc/iomem

Answer (score 0):

The **title** of your question gets an answer : read or write to the `/dev/kmem` device node. (*1)

But… reading your question… I don't think it is precisely what you are looking for.

---

I understand that you want to read/write to some specific register of some device.

Whatever hardware device (including RAM) being communicating with the cpus via one particular bus, real addresses of devices' I/O registers are relevant only with regard to the bus the devices use.
In other words, accessing those addresses… will require to follow a strict and particular protocol and possibly different read/write instructions.

Fortunately, Linux provides a way which abstracts performing IO across all busses and devices : [Memory Mapped IO.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/device-io.html) and a device node to access to that unified (ram & io) address space : **/dev/mem** (*2)

---

Prior to anything, you must first **ensure that this node exists** on your system. For obvious security reasons, many distro do not enable it or restrict its access. Therefore, check in your kernel .config file that CONFIG_DEVMEM is set and CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM is not set.
If it is not the case, use your preferred tool to adapt your kernel configuration accordingly and rebuild your kernel.

---

You then need now to know is the **Address the register was remapped to** :

Contrarily to what you asserted in the OP, you should not be able to know it reading the driver source code since that code is logically written in a base address of the device independent manner.
What you can actually understand from that code is the relative address of the register you are interested in. The offset of its address from the base address. Note it down (or fetch it from the device technical specifications)

The base address to which Linux (if successful) remapped the io space related to your device should be reported in the `/proc/iomem` file. (*3)

Add both (base address and offset) and you get the address the register was remapped.

---

You now need to use the /dev/mem device node and because that is everything but trivial… it is indeed sensible to use [busybox devmem](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/devmem.c). (*4)

Use it as you can read : `devmem ADDRESS [WIDTH [VALUE]]` taking care of the WIDTH parameter (the size in bits of the register)

---

1 : Or possibly **has had** an answer since [Linus Torvalds wanted to get rid of it.](https://lwn.net/Articles/851531/)

2 : On x86_64 architectures, Linux offers another way to deal with devices (reporting port adresses in /proc/ioports and accessing via /dev/port) but since this is not made available for arm arches and OP using arm, accessing to device registers thanks to remapped IO is the only method described here.

3 : Take care, with some devices, the memory remapped ranges can be split in several places. Read the specs (or the driver code) in order to know to which base address the register refers.

4 : **BIG FAT WARNING :** Even through mediate tools such as devmem, inappropriate use of `/dev/mem` can break your system.